# How to comment a bash script in a gitconfig alias

Tags: bash, git

I have the following script in a .gitconfig alias:

```
[alias]
    vx = "!f() { # I want to put a comment here \
                 foo='foo'; \
                 bar='bar'; \
                 separator=': '; \
                 # Comment Here As well \
                 result="${foo}${separator}${bar}"; \
                 echo $result; \
             }; f"
```

If works fine if I remove the comments.  However, with the comments the script just fails to run.  Do comments inside a gitconfig alias use an operator different from `#`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `git config alias.vx` and you will see the alias is printed as a long single line. You cannot insert a shell comment in the middle of a line — comments start with `#` and ends at end-of-line. Once `bash` sees `#` it ignores the rest of the line.

The only workaround I can think of is to insert dummy commands that contain quoted strings. Like `: Text;` (`:` is a no-op command in shells; see https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash, section "Shell Builtin Commands") or `echo Comment >/dev/null;`

```
[alias]
    vx = "!f() { : I want to put a comment here; \
                 foo='foo'; \
                 bar='bar'; \
                 separator=': '; \
                 : Comment Here As well; \
                 result="${foo}${separator}${bar}"; \
                 echo $result; \
             }; f"
```

Comment: That's perfect.  The key here is that even the comments need a semicolon at the end.  Otherwise the next line is treated as a comment as well.

Comment: @AngryHacker It's not a comment. It's a no-op command (ab)used as a comment. As a command it surely needs a semicolon.