# How can I create a multiline git alias that runs a script?

Tags: git, alias

I am trying to create an alias to remove all branches merged to my current branch. To do so, I wanted to turn [the script in Andrew C.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10610327/delete-all-local-git-branches/26152574#26152574) into a git alias, but because it is a multi line script I run into an error.

Comment: An example of a multiline alias: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66041712/7976758

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by

1. Making sure all single quotes in the script are changed to double quotes.
2. Starting to type my alias, **leaving the single quotes open**: `git config --global alias.delete-merged-branches '!for mergedBranch in $(git for-each-ref --format "%(refname:short)" --merged HEAD refs/heads/)` *note the lack of single quote at the end*
3. This opens the possibility to introduce more than one line of code. The alias command will finish when the closing single quote is introduced.

Full example:

```sh
$ git config --global alias.delete-merged-branches '!for mergedBranch in $(git for-each-ref --format "%(refname:short)" --merged HEAD refs/heads/) # leave single quote open
$ > do
$ >    git branch -d ${mergedBranch}
$ > done' # Notice the closing single quote here
```

**EDIT** Has nothing to do with the issue, but the merit of the script goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26152574/8699916 this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You also can create a separate script file: `your_alias_script.sh`

And then reference it from git config:

```
[alias]
    aliasname = bash -c /path/to/your_alias_script.sh
```

Comment: You don't need `bash -c` but you need a bang `!`